# PHP ssh2_scp_send()'s process won't exit when upload error happens

Tags: php, ssh, sftp

Here is a code snippet using PHP's `ssh2_scp_send()` function, trying to upload a file to a ssh server:

```
<?php

$conn = ssh2_connect('192.168.86.241', 22);
ssh2_auth_password ($conn, $username, $password);
if (ssh2_scp_send($this->connection, $local_file, $remote_file)) {
    echo 'error';
} else {
    echo 'done';
}
```

My problem is that, when sending a large file, or if I deliberately kill the ssh server, then this script's process will not exits automatically, and end up eating all the client machines resource.

A `strace` in linux or `dtruss` in mac show that the process keeps calling `recvfrom()`, here are the screenshots of the commands's result:

[image]
[image]